# Can't get Qemu output through SSH

Tags: ssh, qemu, ncurses

### Short Version

I want to run Qemu on a remote machine using ssh. With this command I am able to see some boot messages but I can't manage to get vm the login prompt in my local terminal.

```
qemu-system-i386 -m 128 
-kernel bzImage -drive file=rootfs.ext2,if=virtio 
-append "console=ttyS0" 
-net nic,model=virtio 
-net user 
-nographic
```

I've also tried with `-curses` without success

### Long Version

I have a raspberry with TinyCore where I want to run (using SSH) a BuildRoot distro on qemu.

When I run qemu locally (without SSH)

- using `-nographic`, I can see some boot messages and nothing else
- Using `-curses`, I see `VGA Graphic Mode`, then some boot messages and then it shows `1024 x 768 Graphic Mode` and I can't interact with it anymore

When I run qemu remotely (with SSH) I can only see the boot messages and nothing else.

I don't want to use VNC, how can I do this?

**EDIT:**

On the remote host machine (piCore) I have this in `/etc/inittab`

```
tty1::respawn:/sbin/getty -nl /sbin/autologin 38400 tty1
```

And on the remote guest machine I have this in `/etc/inittab`

```
tty1::respawn:/sbin/getty -L tty1 0 vt100
```

Comment: It’s not curses, but with ``-nographic`` the guest console is redirected to stdio.

Comment: Hi, I've seen many suggesting both as possible solutions ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710555/how-to-use-qemu-to-run-a-non-gui-os-on-the-terminal) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22967925/running-qemu-remotely-via-ssh)). Anyway, with `-nographic` or `-curses` passing `-append "console=ttyS0" I can see some boot messages but still no login prompt.  If I remove `-curses` or `-nographic` I can see the login prompt, but I have to use VNC.

Comment: Are you starting a `getty` on `/dev/ttyS0` in the VM in the first place?

Comment: Hi, I think the instruction that starts a getty is in `/etc/inittab` (I am not experienced on this, I may be wrong), so I have updated the question with the `inittab` of the remote host and guest. I have already tried `-nographic -append "console=tty1"` but It doesn't show any output.

Comment: ttyS0 is the serial device. You do want the console to go there and you need a getty on it if you want to login on that virtual serial port. You don't need the tty1 line if you don't add a graphics card to that VM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `-nographic`, `qemu` doesn't add a virtual graphics card to the VM, still adds a serial controller but with the serial port connected to qemu's stdin/stdout (as opposed to a SDL window when not using `-nographics`).

You're telling the Linux kernel booted in that VM to send its console output to the serial port which is good, but if you also want to have a login prompt there, you need to have a `getty` issue it there.

So, you need to add a line for it in your `inittab` (or other relevant configuration file depending on which init system is being used in the VM):

```
ttyS0::respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS0 115200 vt100
```

Since that VM doesn't have a graphics card, you can also remove the `tty1` line which is only for a virtual VGA terminal.

Comment: This works, thanks!! I've compiled buildroot setting: `TTY Port = ttyS0`, `baudrate = 115200` and `Terminal Environment = v100` in `System Configs > Run getty login..`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use X11 tunneling with SSH.

Try to run "ssh -X -Y user@remot_host".

Then check the variable DISPLAY is defined : "echo $DISPLAY"

If this does not work, you should check the configuration of your sshd daemon in "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" on your serving host. Edit it in order to allow X11 forwarding, then restart your sshd daemon.

Run "xclock" to check whether X is tunneled.

Then QEMU should show its window on the client side of ssh.

Comment: I'm gonna try this and let you know, thanks!